# SAS LIBNAME a directory containing folders with datasets

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I was wondering if I could libname a directory containing serveral folders with datasets I need.

The directory looks like this:

```
Directory_A
--Directory_B
----Dataset_1.sas7bdat
--Directory_C
----Dataset_2.sas7bdat
----Dataset_3.sas7bdat
--Directory_D
----Dataset_4.sas7bdat
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot point a library at a parent folder and automatically display all the subfolder contents, however you *can* configure a "concatenated libname" with each of the individual subfolders like so:

```
libname yourlib ('Directory_B' 'Directory_C' 'Directory D');
```

You can also mix and match with existing librefs, eg:

```
libname yourlib ('Directory_B' librefX 'Directory C');
```

for more info, see [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000933322.htm).